# Get kubernetes image from container registry

Tags: kubernetes, container-registry

Is it possible to get a list of available images from Kubernetes container registry? Preferably by REST API.

Comment: As far as I know, Kubernetes doesn't have a docker registry. You can install a local docker registry as a Kubernetes pod or on a separate environment or machine. After installing the docker registry, you can get the list of available repositories using this api endpoint: https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#listing-repositories

Comment: can you be more precise? do you have a registry running on k8s or do you want to get the list of images that are used in your k8s cluster? (not in the registry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "standard" `k8s.gcr.io` registry used honors [docker's Registry API](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#tags)

```sh
curl -H 'accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json' \
  https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/kube-apiserver/tags/list \
  | jq .tags
```